# Profiling Linux Kernel Modules

Tags: linux, profiling, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am interested in profiling a module for the Linux Kernel. I tried it this way:

1. Built the kernel with `CONFIG_PROFILING=y`
2. Booted the kernel with `profile=2`
3. Reset the profiler by `echo 123 > /proc/profile`
4. The module was successfully loaded by a dedicated daemon
5. Run a user-space app that is using the module through specific `ioctl` calls. The test app worked as expected so the module was working OK.
6. Read the profiling info using `readprofile -p /proc/profile -m System.map` where *System.app* was generated along with the kernel.

So far, so good. Almost everything worked as expected. What *did not* work however, is that I didn't get any info about my module, i.e. there was no mention of any function from the module.

However, on second thoughts, I remebered that I forgot to ***recompile*** the module using the `CONFIG_PROFILING=y`.

So, my question is: *Did the module not show up in the profiling log because it had not been compiled with the `CONFIG_PROFILING=y` or is there some other more obvious reason that I don't know of?*

If one wonders, why I am asking rather than trying it straight away, that is because, I can't do it at home and I'd rather like to hear what the *knowledgable* would say before I get access to the code again.

Comment: I don't know. I would think your guess about the problem is correct since the common way to have profiling information is for the compiler to instrument the code. But, I'm wondering, does oprofile not work for your purposes? - http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/

Comment: Thanks! Oprofile seems to have a rather tedious installation and I'm not sure it supports ARM CPUs.

Comment: It's been a long time since I did anything in a *n*x kernel, but it has to be possible to run your module under a debugger like GDB. Then you can use [this basic technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Comment: can you put here the source code? please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible for modules to be profiled in this way as they are loaded *dynamically*, which means that they are *missing from the System.map file*.

A solution would be to *build the driver into the kernel*. Unfortunately, this does not always work as the system may be designed to run only with the driver built into a module.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that using [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/) should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use it on an ARM.